# ipad - how can I make a Login dialog easily ? such as this one?

Tags: ipad, uiview, authentication

Hello How Can I make a login view easily like this?

It seems username and password are both in a table?

Also I see some system preferences editing uses this kind of label+textfield thing.

Can someone tell me whether I can directly use some views in the lib, or I have to build the view on my own

I mean the username password part in the pic, not the whole window, not including the tool bar, etc.

thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use UITableView with Grouped cells style and two customs cells for username and password.